# Listing Python code with strings and all characters

Tags: characters, strings, python

I have a little issue concerning the representation of a string in Python.

I have the following Python code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import math
import string
from vmtk import pypes
from vmtk import vmtkscripts

seedPointCoordinates = "399 268 364"
targetPointCoordinates = [" 367 264 361 " , "344 287 336 " , " 336 289 330 " , " 315 287 330 " , " 294 278 325 " , " 269 254 321 "  ]

for x in range (0,6,1):
myInitializationArguments = "vmtkimageinitialization -ifile     <PATH>"\XA_001.dcm -interactive 0 -method fastmarching -upperthreshold 11000  -lowerthreshold 2000 -sourcepoints "+seedPointsOne+" -targetpoints "+targetPointsOne[x]+" -olevelsetsfile <PATH>\initialLevelSets"+str(x+1)+".vti"
myPype = pypes.PypeRun(myinitializationArguments)
myArgumentsForMarchingCubes = "vmtkmarchingcubes –ifile <PATH>\initialLevelSets"+str(x+1)+".vti   -ofile <PATH>\initialLevelSets"+str(x+1)+"mc.vtp"
myPype = pypes.PypeRun(myArgumentsForMarchingCubes)
```

which I include with the following LaTeX command:

```latex
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, label={lst:label32}, showstringspaces=false, extendedchars=true,keepspaces=true, tabsize=4, morekeywords={models, lambda, forms}, commentstyle={\rmfamily\catcode`\$=11}, columns=flexible,texcl,showspaces=false, captionpos=b,caption=Example of using the segmentation script with the help of the PypePad command and a Pypes object.]{./PythonCodePart.py}
```

My problem is that the `-` signs don't appear after compiling. And there is also an issue with the construct `<PATH>`...

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable and self-contained (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is just one hyphen that disappears, that is, the first one in line 14; the problem is that you typed U+2013 (EN-DASH) instead of a hyphen.

Comment: @egreg, yes that was another problem, but still.. the - (minus sign) doesn't appear, compiled it twices, no command renewed etc... Thanks however for pointing the dash thing out!

Comment: have you tried the `minted`-package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: there's an indentation error in the for-loop, but I'm too lazy to upload a new image.

A quik'n'derty example of `minted` as an alternative to the `lstlisting`-package. Taking the above code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{Python}
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import math
import string
from vmtk import pypes
from vmtk import vmtkscripts

seedPointCoordinates = "399 268 364"
targetPointCoordinates = [" 367 264 361 " , "344 287 336 ",
 " 336 289 330 " , " 315 287 330 " , " 294 278 325 " , " 269 254 321 "]

for x in range (0,6,1):
    myInitializationArguments = "vmtkimageinitialization -ifile <PATH>"
    \XA_001.dcm -interactive 0 -method fastmarching
    -upperthreshold 11000  -lowerthreshold 2000 -sourcepoints " 
    +seedPointsOne+ 
    " -targetpoints "
    +targetPointsOne[x]+
    " -olevelsetsfile <PATH>\initialLevelSets"+str(x+1)+".vti"

    myPype = pypes.PypeRun(myinitializationArguments)

    myArgumentsForMarchingCubes = "vmtkmarchingcubes –ifile <PATH>\initialLevelSets" 
    +str(x+1)+ ".vti   -ofile <PATH>\initialLevelSets"
    +str(x+1)+ "mc.vtp"
    myPype = pypes.PypeRun(myArgumentsForMarchingCubes)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

with some clean up results in

[image]

Comment: thank you! even if quick'n'derty, it is still a solution!